# Use external System.Common.DBTransaction with Entity Framework 5

Tags: c#, entity-framework, transactions, ado.net, dbconnection

i'm stuck within a problem that is going to happen to everyone in ADO.NET mixed with Entity Framework contexts.
I've got a big procedure that handles and saves data into database by using multiple ways like ADO.NET dataadapters and direct CRUD commands against DB. All the procedure is wrapped by 2 using() blocks that creates and releases a DBConnection/DBTransaction and a try/catch block to commit or rollback the transaction. Unfortunately, in the middle of this routine, i have to recall a saving procedure implemented by using Entity Framework. This leads me to a problem:

According to the official documentation, Entity Framework 5 allows me to pass a connection with an transaction associated transaction (it should work, in debug mode, when i call SaveChanges() i don't receive any TimeOutException due to deadlocks, conversely if i pass a new connection it does), but unfortunately after SaveChanges() kicks in the connection is closed and associated transaction committed! Even if i set the flag 'contextOwnsConnection'!

As far as i know, if i migrate EF5 to EF6, things should work (am i right?), but unfortunately i can't, because the project i'm working on is very large and involves a lot of dependecies and it would take a large amount of time.

How can i make it work with EF5? Is there any trick or pattern to achieve the desired result? Am i right about the behavior of EF6? Does it worth EF6 migration?

Here you are a simple example of how does my code looks like.
For privacy reasons i can't post the original code but just imagine a situation like this with a lot of more complexity:

```
   using(DbConnection conn = DBProvider.CreateConnection()){

            //Open the created connection
            conn.Open();

            //Create a new transaction
            using(DbTransaction tr = DBProvider.CreateTransaction()){

              //Begin a new transaction
              tr.Begin();

              bool saveOk;
              try{

                  //Updates customers by using dataadapter
                  dataAdapterCustomers.InsertCommand.Transaction = tr; 
                  dataAdapterCustomers.UpdateCommand.Transaction = tr;
                  dataAdapterCustomers.DeleteCommand.Transaction = tr;
                  dataAdapterCustomers.Update();

                  //Updates stock items by using dataadapter
                  stockAdapterCustomers.InsertCommand.Transaction = tr; 
                  stockAdapterCustomers.UpdateCommand.Transaction = tr;
                  stockAdapterCustomers.DeleteCommand.Transaction = tr;
                  stockAdapterCustomers.Update();  

                  //...Many other DB accessing here... 

                  //Updates stock quantity by using simple DBCommand
                  quantityUpdateCmd.Transaction = tr;
                  quantityUpdateCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                  //Updates stock statistics by using a simple DBCommand
                  updateStockStatsCmd.Transaction = tr;
                  updateStockStatsCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();


                  //...Many other DB accessing here... 

                  //HERE:
                  //Creates a new activity and save it using EF.
                  //I use a UnitOfWork and i pass to it my connection and 'false' as contextOwnsConnection parameter 
                  //(it 'll be used by the DBContext contained in my Unit of work)
                  using(ActivityUoW uow = new ActivityUoW(conn, false)){

                     Activity act = new Activity();
                     act.Name = "Saving activity";
                     act.Description = "Done by user";
                     act.Date = DateTime.Now;

                     uow.Activities.Add(act);
                     uow.SaveChanges();
                   }


                  //Based on activity result, launch a store procedure that makes other complex things. 
UNFORTUNATELY THE CONNECTION HAS BEEN CLOSED AND TRANSACTION COMMITTED, SO THE FOLLOWING INSTRUCTION WILL FAIL.

                  launchActivityUpdateSpCmd.Transaction = tr;
                  launchActivityUpdateSpCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();


                   //...Many other DB accessing here... 

                   //Data saved correctly  
                   saveOk = true;

               }
               catch(Exception ex){

                  //There was an error during save
                  saveOk = false;
               }


               //Commit or rollback transaction according to save procedure result 
               if(saveOk) 
                 tr.Commit();
               else
                 tr.Rollback();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't quite follow your question(s) and wasn't sure if your issue was related to how to handle transactions or if you had a question about EF5 to EF6 migrations. That being said, you have an interesting mixture of data access code.

Regarding transactions - I would look into using the [TransactionScope](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope(v=vs.110).aspx) which is part of the [System.Transactions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions(v=vs.110).aspx) namespace.

For example:

```
    try
    {
        using (var scope = new TransactionScope())
        {
            using (var conn = new SqlConnection("your connection string"))
            {
                conn.Open();
                // your EF and ADO.NET code
            }

            scope.Complete();
        }
    }
    catch (TransactionAbortedException ex)
    {

    }
    catch (ApplicationException ex)
    {

    }
```

Comment: TransactionScope sounds good, it should work for setting up the transaction in my scope. But what about connection closing after EF SaveContext()? Does EF leave DbConnection open in transaction scope? If i doesn't, what can i do apart from migrating from EF5 to EF6?

Comment: Your connection object is in a using block. The connection will be closed.Using block calls Dispose().

Comment: Yes i know that, but what about launchActivityUpdateSpCmd command? It doesn't work because at that point connection is already closed due to EF5 SaveChanges() behavior of the previous lines of code.

Comment: It doesn't work with your current code? Or it doesn't work using the TransactionScope?

Comment: The current code is not running, i haven't tried yet to use TransactionScope because the real case is very complex, so i asked you if you know something about automatic connection closing of EF5, even if the connection iis passed by the client ;-)

Comment: Got it. I don't explicitly know the answer regarding automatic connection closing on EF5. That being said it seems using TransactionScope will address your issue, but you obviously have to test it. Refer to the answer on the following MSDN post. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c12e55ea-5907-4bce-9b57-917cb5e118a6/transaction-scope-and-sql-connection-with-using-statement?forum=windowstransactionsprogramming